# Multiple solutions for a particle in an infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, superposition

I am starting to learn about quantum mechanics and was wondering about the solutions to a question about a particle in an infinite potential well of length $L$. 
The solutions are:
$$\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L} \right)$$

And I was wondering what is the meaning of $n$. Isn't there supposed to be only one wave function? In that case, $\Psi = \sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_n \psi_n$, but what are the $a_n$? Or maybe it is probabilistic, and we don't know which $\psi_n$ the particle is currently in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions $\psi_n(x)$ to the time-independent Schrodinger equation are basis solutions which can be combined to obtain perfectly general solutions:
$$
\psi(x)=\sum_n a_n\psi_n(x) \tag{1}
$$
In $\psi_n(x)$, the integer $n$ simply labels the different solutions, which have different energies given by
$$
E_n=\frac{n^2\hbar^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}\, .
$$
Of course, a function like $\psi(x)$
is *not* in general a solution of the time-independent Schrodinger equation; nevertheless, it is a perfectly valid wavefunction if it satisfies the boundary conditions of the problem (and, in your case, is normalizable).
For example, the function 
$$
\psi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{30}{L^5}}x(x-L)
$$
satisfies the boundary condition of the infinite well and is thus a legitimate wavefunction: it is not a solution to the time-independent Schrodinger equation
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)\ne E\psi(x)
$$
for any $E$ but $\psi(x)$ can be expanded as
$$
\sqrt{\frac{30}{L^5}}x(x-L)=\sum_m a_m \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin
\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)\, .
$$

If the time-dependent solutions are $\Psi_n(x,t)=e^{iE_nt/\hbar}\psi_n(x)$, then the combination
$$
\Psi(x,t)=\sum_n a_n e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\psi_n(x)
$$
*is* solution to the *time-dependent* Schrodinger equation
$$
i \hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\Psi(x,t)=H\Psi(x,t) \tag{2}
$$
provided $H\Psi_n(x,t)=E_n\Psi_n(x,t)$.  Inserting $t=0$ in Eq.(2) yields Eq.(1), i.e. the function $\psi(x)$ defined by the superposition is the solution $\Psi(x,t)$ evaluated at some specified time.

This is not an uncommon situation: for instance, a pulse is linear combination of plane waves
$$
\phi(x,t)=\int dk c(k)e^{i(kx-\omega t)} \tag{3}
$$
where the function $c(k)$ determines the shape of the pulse, and the heat equation is solved by summing Fourier components.

The $a_n$'s are thus a discrete version of the $c(k)$'s defining the shape of the pulse of Eq.(3).  Like $c(k)$, $a_n$ can be real or complex.  The $c(k)$'s can be obtained by Fourier analysis, and the $a_n$ likewise can be recovered using the orthogonality property of the solutions $\psi_n(x)$:
$$
a_n=\int dx\, \psi(x)\psi^*_n(x)\, .
$$
The real number $\vert a_m\vert^2$ is the probability of obtaining the energy $E_m$ when the system is described by $\Psi(x,t)$.

Comment: So if I would know the energy of the system would I be able to know $\Psi$?

Comment: The system is NOT is a state of definite energy unless it is in an eigenstate $\psi_n(x)$.  For a given $\Psi(x)$ you can calculate $\langle E\rangle$ but there is a non-zero $\Delta E$ to your system.  If by knowing "the energy of the system" you mean $\langle E\rangle$ then you cannot know $\Psi(x)$.  You can only deduce $\Psi(x)$ if $\Psi(x)=\psi_n(x)$ for a single $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the $\psi_n$ represent eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian of your system. 
This is, each one of them is a possible state of the system with well-defined energy, given by its eigenvalue $E_n=\frac{(n\hbar\pi)^2}{2mL^2}$

Since Schrödinger's equation is linear, any linear combination of the $\psi_n$ is also a possible state of your system, albeit it would have no well-defined energy (you'd get different results when measuring energy on that kind of systems, with the energy of the eigenstates with bigger coeficients being more porbable).

However, these are **possible** states, it doesn't mean that your system will be in all of the eigenfuntions and their linear combinations, but that for your system to be in a particular state $\phi$, it must be a linear combination of the eigenvalues $\psi_n$.

The infinite sum you write is the most general expression for a "linear" (it isn't linear because the sum is infinite, but it fortunately works as if it was) combination of the eigenstates, with $a_n$ being the linear coefficient of $\psi_n$. Because of the above, all allowed states can be written in this form.

Comment: So how do I find the $a_n$?

Comment: Since the $\psi_n$ form an orthonormal base, the scalar product of your particular $\Psi$ and $\psi_m$ yields $a_m$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Don't I want to find $\Psi$?

Comment: No, there is not a single $\Psi$, anything that can be written as a linear combination of the eignstates (infinite or not) can be a $\Psi$, that is , a possible state of the system.The $a_n$ are just the complex coefficients of that linear combination. They are different for each $\Psi$.

Comment: @Mario Does the same apply also to a wave on a string (in classical mechanics)? Is the wavefunction a superposition of the normal modes?