# Set of probabilities distributions inside a infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

Its been some years since I did the infinite square well. I am doing an econimics problems with probability distributions and I vaguly remember there being a name for either the wave functions in the inifinte square well, or the probability distributions.

What is the equation if the well is between [0,1]? The equation of all possible probablity distributions, including the harmonics.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328370/

Comment: If you are just after the name, rather than the formulae, were you perhaps thinking of eigenfunctions, or eigenstates?

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

The energy eigenstates for the infinite square well between $0$ and $a$ are $$E(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$
with energies $$E_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2ma}$$
The general solution for any initial wavefuntion $\psi(x,0)$ is $$\psi(x,t)=\frac{2}{a}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\exp\left(-i\frac{n^2\pi^2}{2ma}t\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)\psi(x,0)\right]$$
Simply set $a=1$ for your desired equations.

---

### Derivation

For any time-independent system, after calculating the eigenkets of $H$, we have $$\begin{align}
i\hbar\partial_t\langle E | \psi\rangle&=E\langle E | \psi\rangle\\
\langle E | \psi(t)\rangle&=e^{-iEt/\hbar}\langle E | \psi(0)\rangle\end{align}$$
Thus, assuming discrete values of $E$, we have $$\begin{align}\langle x | \psi\rangle &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\langle x | E_n\rangle\langle E_n | \psi\rangle\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\langle x | E_n\rangle e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\langle E_n | \psi(0)\rangle \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\langle x | E_n\rangle\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx'\langle E_n | x'\rangle\langle x'| \psi(0)\rangle\end{align}$$
Converting to function notation, we have $$\psi(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-iE_nt/\hbar} E_n(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx E^\star_n(x) \psi(x,0)$$
Now, for the infinite square well, the eigenvalue equation is $$\frac{1}{2m}P^2|E\rangle=(E-V_0)| E\rangle$$ Outside the well, the probability of the particle being found there is zero (which I will not prove). Inside, $V_0=0$. Converting to the position basis, we have $$\begin{align}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}d_x E(x)&=E\cdot E(x) \\
E(x)&=A\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}x\right)+B\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}x\right)\end{align}$$
However, we must have $E(0)=E(a)=0$; thus, $B=0$ and either $A=0$ or $\sin(a\sqrt{2mE}/\hbar)=0$. Since $\sin(x)=0$ iff $x=n\pi,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $$E_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2ma}$$ and $$E(x)=A\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$
After normalization, $$E(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$
Plugging these into the general formula derived above returns the answer given above. This derivation is rather terse; refer to a standard undergraduate text in the field for more clarity (such as Shankar or Griffiths).